# Machine restarts abruptly

Tags: 12.04, restart

I'm running on 12.04.2, and over the last two days, there have been 3 incidences where my computer has re started. No warning message, nothing, it just blanked out and started itself again. Everything that i was working on and that wasn't saved was lost, because it wasn't normal behavior on the machine's part, so it's getting pretty annoying.

Any ideas regarding this?

Plus, is there any output that I should post here, that'd make understanding the problem simpler?

EDIT: this is the ubuntu pastebin link for the dmesg log
http://paste.ubuntu.com/5655768/

EDIT-2: second pastebin link
http://paste.ubuntu.com/5655840/

Comment: What is the model of your computer? Seems there are a few Dell issues according to this http://reqorts.qa.ubuntu.com/reports/kernel-bugs/reports/30-day-new.html

Comment: it's an Acer TravelMate P643 series.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a hardware problem.

It could be:

1) A loose RAM. Make sure your RAM cards are pressed tight till it clicks is securely.

2) It could be your SMPS has become faulty.

3) It could be your CPU fans have stopped working so the PC is overheating thus switching off randomly & on its own. If the insides of the PC is caked with dust it could overheat. So please open it & check & clean if needed.

4) The UPS (if there is one) could be at fault.

Comment: i guess i should've mentioned this, i'm running it on my laptop, these are problems that desktops tend to have, no?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the output of some of your logs to gauge possible issues.

A good start is the `dmesg` log.

Type the following to get the last 2000 lines of the log, if the problem occurred more than a day ago 2000 lines might not be enough lines. Ideally you do this after the problem occurs so we have a snapshot of the most recent issue.

```
dmesg | tail -n 2000 > output.txt
```

This will generate a file called `output.txt`

Instead of adding that output to your question use Ubuntu paste bin http://paste.ubuntu.com/ which will give you a link that you can paste into your question

Looking at your log the critical area just before the restart occurs at the daily cron job...

```
May 12 00:13:48 JARVIS anacron[8436]: Will run job `cron.daily' in 5 min.
May 12 00:13:48 JARVIS anacron[8436]: Jobs will be executed sequentially
May 12 00:14:16 JARVIS NetworkManager[908]: <warn> error monitoring device for netlink events: error processing netlink message: Out of memory
May 12 00:17:01 JARVIS CRON[8543]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
May 12 00:17:16 JARVIS NetworkManager[908]: <warn> error monitoring device for netlink events: No buffer space available
May 12 00:18:48 JARVIS anacron[8436]: Job `cron.daily' started
May 12 00:18:48 JARVIS anacron[8550]: Updated timestamp for job `cron.daily' to 2013-05-12
May 12 00:22:16 JARVIS NetworkManager[908]: <warn> error monitoring device for netlink events: No buffer space available
May 12 00:25:51 JARVIS kernel: imklog 5.8.6, log source = /proc/kmsg started.
May 12 00:25:51 JARVIS rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="5.8.6" x-pid="937" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start
May 12 00:25:51 JARVIS rsyslogd: rsyslogd's groupid changed to 103
May 12 00:25:51 JARVIS rsyslogd: rsyslogd's userid changed to 101
```

The key areas to watch are the lines before `kernel: imklog 5.8.6, log source = /proc/kmsg started` as that is where the log starts after a reboot so the lines before it are what happened just before the error kicked in. Take a note of the events that occured before your other reboots and see if you can see a trend.

I know this is not an answer, but you have a way forward to fault find until you find another answer.

Comment: done, and the problem occurred when i posted the question, ie, i posted it as soon as my machine re-booted.

Comment: posted the second link

Comment: ah, yes, that i have noticed. i get a similar message each time i resume a session, and i'd compared xdiagnose's output with that of the error.

Comment: i'm sorry, but i really can't get much from the log. could you explain?

Comment: @Projjol overall the Logs don't have any glaring errors that pinpoint your issue. So we can make two conclusions, kernel bug or hardware fault. My bet is on the latter until you get a more obvious error in the logs

Comment: Indeed, it seems more likely that it's a hardware fault. Any diagnosis tests for it that i can run?